# Angular directive not rendering in ionic app

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, ionic-framework

I am using [Ionic framework](http://ionicframework.com) to create an application.

I need to be able to reuse and change my app header so I declare my two different headers as directives using my working markup.

```
app.directive('headerSidebar', function(){
  return {
    templateUrl: 'templates/header-main.html',
    restrict: 'E'
  };
});

app.directive('headerBack', function(){
  return {
    templateUrl: 'templates/header-back.html',
    restrict: 'E'
  };
});
```

When I try to call the directives with `<header-sidebar></header-sidebar>` or `<header-back></header-back>` nothing happens.

My html is valid and my template urls are correct. I have tried changing the names of both my directives and my templates but nothing worked.

I am using the [Ionic sidebar layout](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionNavView/) and I call my directives inside my `ion-nav-view`:

```
 <body ng-app="starter">

    <ion-side-menus>

      <ion-side-menu-content>
        <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
      </ion-side-menu-content>

      <sidebar></sidebar>

    </ion-side-menus>

  </body>
```

Any suggestions to how I could solve this or reorganize my code to better include the header bars?

Comment: I'm just now running into this same problem. It appears that any directive with a templateUrl will not load that template externally once the app is built in iOS. Were you able to figure this issue out?

Comment: I haven't solved it yet. I gave up and copied the markup in everywhere. I have the problem even before built.

Comment: My issue ended up being a little bit different than yours I guess. Upon further inspection I realized that I had a '/' before all of my templateUrls that was actually causing the issue.

Comment: Same thing with templateUrl not rendering directives on android

Comment: @WillHitchcock Thank you very much, this did the trick for me!

Comment: @Will Hitchcock You should post this as an answer so that it is easier to find :)

Answer (score 9):

My issue ended up being a little bit different than yours I guess. Upon further inspection I realized that I had a '/' before all of my templateUrls that was actually causing the issue

Comment: Had a similar issue, the problem was with the template url having ../ at the front of it

Comment: Relative paths work great in the browser, but not in the compiled app. Thanks Will for saving me on this one :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue. This is due to the relative path in URL. This works fine in the browsers but not in App. I removed `../` from the URL path.